# Finding average using pivot

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

studentname I   II
Vivek Johari    30  20
Chandra Singh   30  20
Avinash Dubey   30  25
Pankaj Kumar    33  29
I have a table named student with details as above.
I want to find the average of column I and II and display it on a new column using pivot.
Please help me to solve this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about trying something like [Computed Column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250.aspx) when you create the table.
This will help you calculate the average value automatically.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ComputeCOL](
[Studentname] [nchar](10) NULL,
[I] [float] NULL,
[II] [float] NULL,
[AVG]  AS (([I]+[II])/(2))
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: Please help me to solve this using pivot... May I use any sub query to solve this using pivot..

Comment: Can you let me know your expected result?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to display it using PIVOT? I am not with you. But to display the average in another column try this :

```
SELECT StudentName
   ,   Col1
   ,   Col2
   ,   (Col1 + Col2 ) / 2  AS [Average]

FROM [TableNAme]
```

If this helps, please tick it off, if not give me more info.
Thanks

Mac

Comment: Please help me to solve this using pivot... May I use any sub query to solve this using pivot..